# Parsing JSON with Powershell - get a value based on another value

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

I am executing an API request that receives a JSON response. The response looks like this (shortened for the purpose of this question):

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "url": "https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/12345.json",
            "id": 12345,
            "external_id": null,
            "via": {
                "channel": "email",
                "source": {
                    "from": {
                        "address": "person@yahoo.com.au",
                        "name": "Person Name"
                    },
                    "to": {
                        "name": "Company",
                        "address": "info@company.com.au"
                    },
                    "rel": null
                }
            },
            "created_at": "2023-04-17T00:08:14Z",
            "updated_at": "2023-04-17T00:08:14Z",
            "type": null,
            "subject": "Re: Dispatch Advice",
            "raw_subject": "Re: Dispatch Advice",
            "description": "email body",
            "priority": "normal",
            "status": "open",
            "recipient": "info@company.com.au",
            "requester_id": 17600210801689,
            "submitter_id": 17600210801689,
            "assignee_id": null,
            "organization_id": null,
            "group_id": 4480945892505,
            "collaborator_ids": [],
            "follower_ids": [],
            "email_cc_ids": [],
            "forum_topic_id": null,
            "problem_id": null,
            "has_incidents": false,
            "is_public": true,
            "due_at": null,
            "tags": [],
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "id": 4481790575897,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 10936520871705,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 5536560189977,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "satisfaction_rating": {
                "score": "unoffered"
            },
            "sharing_agreement_ids": [],
            "custom_status_id": 4480835200921,
            "fields": [
                {
                    "id": 4481790575897,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 10936520871705,
                    "value": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 5536560189977,
                    "value": null
                }
            ],
            "followup_ids": [],
            "ticket_form_id": 4480835198361,
            "brand_id": 4480835199385,
            "allow_channelback": false,
            "allow_attachments": true,
            "from_messaging_channel": false,
            "result_type": "ticket"
        },
```

Now, in some cases, the results.via.source.from name and address fields will be blank as the customer has used a form and not emailed in. In this event, the custom fields will contain the data I am after. For example:

```
        {
            "url": "https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/36765.json",
            "id": 36765,
            "external_id": null,
            "via": {
                "channel": "web",
                "source": {
                    "from": {},
                    "to": {},
                    "rel": null
                }
            },
            "subject": "Results enquiry - Name",
            "status": "open",
            "custom_fields": [
                {
                    "id": 4495582893081,
                    "value": "FirstName"
                },
                {
                    "id": 4495561030297,
                    "value": "Surname"
                },
             ]
```

If the via.source.from.name field (or address) is blank, I want the script to get the firstname and lastname plus address from the relevant custom fields. The field IDs will always be the same.

The data is pushed into an SQL Server table, here is the code:

```
$headers=@{}
$headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
$headers.Add("Authorization", "redacted")
$getTkts = Invoke-WebRequest -Method 'GET' -Uri "https://domain.zendesk.com/api/v2/search.json?query=created>48hours type:ticket" -Headers $headers


$tktInfo = $getTkts | ConvertFrom-JSON
$test1 = $tktInfo.results



ForEach ($test in $test1) {
         If ($test.via.source.from.name -eq $Null) {
            $requester_name = "INSERT HERE"
        } Else {
            $requester_name = $test.via.source.from.name
        }

        $sqlData = [PSCustomObject]@{
            ticket_no = $test.id
            submitted = $test.created_at
            feedback_rating = $test.satisfaction_rating.score
            feedback_reason = $test.satisfaction_rating.reason
            feedback_comment = $test.satisfaction_rating.comment
            requester_name = $requester_name
            requester_email = $test.via.source.from.address
            received_at = $test.via.source.to.address
            form_used = $test.ticket_form_id
            channel = $test.via.channel
    }

    Write-SqlTableData -ServerInstance "NP-SQL07" -DatabaseName "Test" -SchemaName "dbo" -TableName "Table_2" -InputData $sqlData
}
```

I have tried using the following under the if statement to insert the name based on those custom fields but none of it seems to work.

```
ForEach ($test in $test1) {
      If ($test.via.source.from.name -eq $Null) {
            $checkData = [PSCustomObject]@{
                firstname = $test.custom_fields.value | Where-Object {$test.custom_fields.id -match "4495582893081"}
                lastname = $test.custom.fields.value | Where-Object {$test.custom_fields.id -match "4495582893081"}
            }
            $requester_name = $checkData.firstname + " " + $checkData.lastname
            Write-Host "VIA==" $test.via.channel
            Write-Host "=== $requester_name ==="
            # $check2.value | where $check2.id -eq '4481808286233'
            #$test1.custom_fields.id, $test1.custom_fields.value | Where-Object {$test1.custom_fields.id -eq "4481808286233"}
        } Else {
            $requester_name = $test.via.source.from.name
        }
```

the above produces a continuous line of all custom_field values instead of only those I have specified:

```
VIA== web
===      False 2023-04-13 ANPA      <redacted> True   True    703 Pacific Highway  <redacted>    <redacted> False    <redacted>    True   2280  <redacted>
```

and trying just one name using a slightly different method

```
$tktInfo = $getTkts | ConvertFrom-JSON
$test1 = $tktInfo.results

ForEach ($test in $test1) {
        $check2 = $test1.custom_fields | Format-Table
         If ($test.via.source.from.name -eq $Null) {
            $requester_name = $check2.value | Where-Object $check2.id -match "4495582893081"
        } Else {
            $requester_name = $test.via.source.from.name
        }
```

gets me

```
Where-Object : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Property'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is not null or empty, 
and then try the command again.
At I:\Information Technology\Scripts and Tools\Pull_Zendesk_Tkt_Stats.ps1:23 char:60
+ ...     $requester_name = $check2.value | Where-Object $check2.id -match  ...
+                                                        ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Where-Object], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WhereObjectCommand
```

What is the best approach here?

Comment: If using PowerShell 7, you might use the [`ConvertFrim-Json -AsHashTable `](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertfrom-json#-ashashtable) parameter which makes it somewhat easier to find the nodes.

Comment: How are you initialising ```$check``` in your penultimate code snippet? And what is ```field_id```? I can't see any reference to those in earlier code or your sample json (the json shows each ```custom_fields``` entry has an ```id``` and ```value``` property, not ```field_id```). Also, your ```where-object``` is a bit screwy in a few different ways - should probably be something like ```firstname = ($check | where-object { $_.id -eq 4481808286233 }).value``` but need more details to confirm...

Comment: Please post **valid** json

Comment: iRon - Thanks, but I am using an earlier version of PS which I can't really get around at the moment

@mclayton - Thanks for the point outs, I really should have checked over the post again. Spent too long on this and had the blinkers on. I've made some updates based on some testing I did this morning, hopefully that gives you an idea.

Comment: ```$check2 = $test1.custom_fields | Format-Table``` - ```Format-Table``` is for **displaying** data for a human to read (e.g. on screen, in log files, etc) - it takes your structured data and converts it to formatting instructions. That's not your only problem, but it's definitely one of them - just do ```$check2 = $test1.custom_fields``` if you want to be able to do downstream processing on the data.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong, but would I not need to use `$check2 = $test.custom_fields` inside the if block instead? My understanding is if I do it outside of this block, I will get the id/value pairs for all returned tickets, and not just the ticket in this iteration of the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sample code has a number of problems - rather than try to pick it apart issue by issue, here's a sample that works. If you have specific questions about why parts of your code *don't* work (or at least don't do what you expect them to do) it might be better to open new questions about them specifically...

First, let's set up some representative test data. We don't need all the properties from the full api response so I've removed a lot of them from your sample json...

```
$json = @"
{
  "results": [
    {
      "via": {
        "source": {
          "from": {}
        }
      },
      "custom_fields": [
        {
          "id": 4495582893081,
          "value": "FirstName"
        },
        {
          "id": 4495561030297,
          "value": "Surname"
        },
      ]
    }
  ]
}
"@

$data = $json | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

Next, process each result in the array. This probably needs some additional error handling for cases where, for example, neither the "name" nor "custom_fields" contain a requester name...

```
# loop through each item in the "results" array
foreach( $result in $data.results )
{

    # try to read the requester name from the default location
    $requester_name = $result.via.source.from.name;

    # if we didn't find the requester name in the default location
    # we look in the "custom_fields" instead
    if( $null -eq $requester_name )
    {
        # find the entry in the "custom_fields" array that has the id 4495582893081,
        # and then get its "value" property
        $requester_name = ($result.custom_fields | where-object { $_.id -eq 4495582893081 }).value;
    }

    # do something with the requester name
    # (we'll just log it to the console for this example)
    write-host $requester_name;

}
```

If I run these two samples locally I get this output, which is what I think you're after:

```
FirstName
```

Comment: Thank you, this has hit the nail on the head! Script is still only in it's early stages so hopefully I'll catch all the issues with it you've found :=)